# How to bind a dropdown to a datagridview without building the columns manually

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to set one of my fields to be a dropdown on a datagridview without a lot of manually code.Currently, I am using AutoGenerateColumns = false and creating the columns and adding them one by one.

```
dataGridView3.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn reasonCode = 
    new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn() {
                                       DataPropertyName = "REASON", 
                                       HeaderText = "Reason Code" 
                                     };
dataGridView3.Columns.Add(reasonCode);
```

This works, but can be tedious to maintain as I add columns. When I let the control autogenerate columns, it is very simple, but I don't know how to make it show the combobox.

The question is: Is there a way to configure the datatable being bound so that the datagridview can know how to display my combobox? Or is there a more efficient way to do this?

Almost all of my columns autogenerate perfectly, it is just this one combobox that is forcing me to manually create all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try manually adding your `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` manually and *then* setting `AutoGenerateColumns` to true to generate the remaining columns.  I haven't tested this though, so I don't know if it will solve your issues.

From [MSDN - DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autogeneratecolumns.aspx):

> Columns are automatically generated when this property is set to true
>   and the DataSource or DataMember properties are set or changed.
>   **Columns can also be automatically generated when the AutoGenerateColumns property is changed from false to true.** If this
>   property is true and the DataSource changes so there are columns that
>   do not match the columns of the previous DataSource value, data in the
>   unmatched columns is discarded. This property is ignored if the
>   DataSource or DataMember properties are not set.

(Emphasis added)